# jQuery History Plugin Error: $.history is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, history

I'm not exactly a novice, but I can't for the life of me figure out why something so simple isn't working.

I'm getting an error `$.history is undefined` when trying to run this jQuery plugin...

http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html

here is my page...

http://hupcapstudios.com/includeTest/getit.php

can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

EDIT:
(BTW. Using FF 3.5 on Mac and reading the error in Error Console)

Comment: you can see it here...
http://hupcapstudios.com/includeTest/error.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$.history.init()` format is from the newer version of the plugin, found here: http://github.com/tkyk/jquery-history-plugin

You just need to update your `jquery.history.js` :)

Comment: thank you!  There are so many versions of it out there, it was hard to track down the most recent.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to be in the misuse of the history plugin. If you read [the source](http://hupcapstudios.com/includeTest/js/jquery.history.js) of the file you've included in your page you'll see it simply doesn't define a `history` member.

I think you're looking for `$.historyInit` instead of `$.history.init`

Comment: you were absolutely right.  I was mixing and matching two different examples. I'd of given you the check mark but Nick supplied the laterst version of the plugin.